# Iterate HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, hashmap

I have three values I get from a json query, and I thought that I would need to store then in a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>` to later, iterate over it and store in a sqlite database, but I don't know how to iterate it.

I have 3 values: a name, product and quantity, and I need to store it with:

```
db.execSQL("Insert into table(name, product , quantity) values ('" + name + "', '" + product + "' + " + quantity + ")");
```

Any idea?

Thanks (Sorry for my English)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Java 8:

```
 mainHash.forEach ((name, products) -> {
       products.forEach ((product, quantity) -> {
             db.execSQL("Insert into table(name, product , quantity) values ('" + name + "', '" + product + "' + " + quantity + ")");
       }
 });
```

In older Java:

```
for (Map.Entry <String, HashMap <String, Integer>> nameEntry: mainHash) {
     String name = nameEntry.getKey();
     for (Map.Entry <String, Integer> productEntry: nameEntry.getValue ()) {
         String product = productEntry.getKey();
         Integer quantity = productEntry.getValue();
          db.execSQL("Insert into table(name, product , quantity) values ('" + name + "', '" + product + "' + " + quantity + ")");
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, how can this be done in android?

Comment: Thanks, that's work! :)